# determine if a set of related values have changed in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2

I am very new to VueJS.

From what I've seen there is probably an elegant answer to this.  I have a table of records.  Clicking on one of them opens a modal and loads that row/record.  My code looks like this (made easier to read):

#### Javascript

```
app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        records: [], //keys have no significance
        focusRecord: { //this object will in the modal to edit, initialize it
            id: '',
            firstname: '',
            lastname: ''
        },
        focusRecordInitial: {}
    },
    created: function(){
        //load values in app.records via ajax; this is working fine!
        app.records = ajax.response.data; //this is pseudo code :)
    },
    methods: {
        loadRecord: function(record){
            app.focusRecord = record; // and this works
            app.focusRecordInitial = record;
        }
    }
});
```

#### Html

```
<tr v-for="record in records">
    <td v-on:click="loadRecord(record)">{{ record.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ record.firstname }} {{ record.lastname }}</td>
</tr>
```

What I'm trying to do is really simple: detect if `focusRecord` has changed after it has been loaded into the modal from a row/record.  Ideally another attribute like `app.focusRecord.changed` that I can reference.  I'm thinking this might be a computed field which I'm learning about, but again with Vue there may be a more elegant way.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use VueJS watchers : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

```
   ...
   watch : {
       focusRecord(newValue, oldValue) {
           // Hey my value just changed
       }
   }
   ...
```

Here is another way to do it, however I didn't know what's refers "focusRecordInitial"

```js
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
       return {
            records: [],
            focusRecordIndex: null
       }
   },
   computed :  {
       focusRecord() {
           if (this.focusRecordIndex == null) return null
           if (typeof this.records[this.focusRecordIndex] === 'undefined') return null
           return this.records[this.focusRecordIndex]
       }
   },
   watch : {
       focusRecord(newValue, oldValue) {
           alert('Changed !')
       }
   },
   created() {
        this.records = [{id: 1, firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe'}, {id: 2, firstname: 'Jane', lastname: 'Doe'}, {id: 3, firstname: 'Frank', lastname: 'Doe'}]
   },
   methods : {
       loadRecord(index) {
           this.focusRecordIndex = index
       }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
    <table>
        <tr v-for="(record, i) in records">
            <td><button @click="loadRecord(i)">{{ record.id }}</button></td>
            <td>{{ record.firstname }} {{ record.lastname }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {{focusRecord}}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm editing a more detailed answer to enhence your solution.

Answer (score 0):

#### Vue Watchers

Vue provides a more generic way to react to data changes through the watch option. This is most useful when you want to perform asynchronous or expensive operations in response to changing data.

[Vue JS Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

You can do something like this:

```
app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        records: [], //keys have no significance
        focusRecord: { //this object will in the modal to edit, initialize it
            id: '',
            firstname: '',
            lastname: ''
        },
        focusRecordInitial: {}
    },
    created: function(){
        //load values in app.records via ajax; this is working fine!
        app.records = ajax.response.data; //this is pseudo code :)
    },
    methods: {
        loadRecord: function(record){
            app.focusRecord = record; // and this works
            app.focusRecordInitial = record;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        loadRecord: function () {
            alert('Record changed');
        }
    }
});
```

You can also check out: Vue JS [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to react to data changes as:

```
watch: {
     'focusRecord': function(newValue, oldValue) {
         /* called whenever there is change in the focusRecord
           property in the data option */
         console.log(newValue); // this is the updated value
         console.log(oldValue); // this is the value before changes 
     }
}
```

The `key` in the `watch` object is the expression you want to watch for the changes.
The expression is nothing but the dot-delimited paths of the property you want to watch.

Example:

```
watch: {
     'focusRecord': function(newValue, oldValue) {
         //do something
     },
     'focusRecord.firstname': function(newValue, oldValue){
         //watch 'firstname' property of focusRecord object
     }
}
```